# How to position fancybox on top

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How to position the fancybox 100px from top by default it is center aligned.

I believe there is no api settings for that. Can anyone help me out in doing it on the actual script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$.fancybox({
   'width'     : 620,
   'height'    : 490,
   'speedIn'    :600,
   'speedOut'   :200,
   'onComplete': function() {
      $("#fancybox-wrap").css({'top':'20px', 'bottom':'auto'});
   }
});
```

Comment: it does not work properly. it moves image to top, but after transistion.

Comment: does not work in my case, for which version of fancybox did this work?

Answer (score 21):

The solution I got working was styling the wrapper like this:

```
#fancybox-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px !important;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I used this as well, but if you have a page where you can scroll down, the fancybox will open on top and you might won't see it at all without scrolling up...

Comment: @basZero: me too. I used the scrollTop in the onComplete event. I used lqthang86's answer

Comment: @Valamas-AUS so you are saying that you successfully implemented fancybox on a long page where it opens on the top of the currently visible page section? Can you post your code as seperate answer please? Thanks a lot... in my case it still does not work.

Comment: yes, a long page and a short page works out the same. i added the onComplete event and scrollTop only code (ignore the additional css) from this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9731058/511438

Comment: @Valamas-AUS does this mean that when fancybox gets opened, the browser scrolls first to the top before it opens the fancybox? That would be a very user unfriendly behaviour. The vertical position within the current page should not change, instead the fancybox should be adjusted so that it seems to open at the top of the current view.

Comment: sure, but i found that on a longer page that when scrolled down, users did not even see the fancy box because it was at the top 100px of the page. Made even worse with the modal appearance that the main behind page without scrolling ability and only able to hack-scroll up using the mouse wheel. so between short and long pages this was my workaround for a rarely used feature; seeing an image which was a size guide for clothes. Sure, if this was a gallery you kept clicking on different images that scroll top would be annoying.

Answer (score 6):

In fancyBox 2 I use `topRatio : 0`, this propery move fancyBox at top, then I used `jQuery().css()` to put it where I want. Example:

```
$("#myfancy").fancybox({
    wrapCSS     : 'fancybox-custom',
    maxWidth    : 500,
    maxHeight   : 360,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '85%',
    height      : '95%',
    autoSize    : false,
    openEffect  : 'fade',
    openSpeed   : 'slow',
    closeEffect : 'fade',
    modal       : true,
    closeSpeed  : 'slow',
    topRatio    : 0,
    helpers         : {
        overlay     : {
            css     : {
                'background-color' : '#fff'
            }
        }
    }
}).trigger('click');
jQuery('.fancybox-wrap').css('margin-top', '120px');
```

Answer (score 4):

scrollTop page.

```
$.fancybox({
       'width'     : 620,
       'height'    : 490,
       'speedIn'    :600,
       'speedOut'   :200,
       'onComplete': function() {
          $(document).scrollTop(0);
          $("#fancybox-wrap").css({'top':'20px', 'bottom':'auto'});
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

This one works. Just add the style after loading the fancybox css. This will overide any movement.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" >
<style type="text/css">div#fancybox-wrap {top:100px !important;}</style>
```

Source

http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/b874901b11414835/111301916450df93?lnk=gst&q=top#111301916450df93

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to position the fancybox a little bit high, you can use this parameter: "topRatio", check out the document at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs.

Comment: topRatio - top space ratio for vertical centering. If set to 0.5 than vertical and bottom spece will be equal. If 0 - fancyBox will be at the viewport top
Number; Default value: 0.5

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    topRatio: 0, 
    afterShow: function(){
        $(".fancybox-wrap").css({"top":0, "margin":"100px 0 0"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Will it not be better to change the value of top to 100px instead of using a margin?

Comment: I appreciate your argument but it won't work like this, topRatio:0 value will set it at top. Then you have to margin it down from top in this case.

Comment: Can you provide a working example? And to clarify, I meant this "top" (not sure if I Was clear)

        $(".fancybox-wrap").css({"top":"100px"});

Answer (score 1):

I tweaked the above code a little bit. And its working fine for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('a.fancybox').each(function(){
            var fWidth = parseInt($(this).attr('href').match(/width=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('width=',''));
            var fHeight = parseInt($(this).attr('href').match(/height=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('height=',''));
            var posTop = parseInt($(this).attr('href').match(/top=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('top=',''));
            var posLeft = parseInt($(this).attr('href').match(/left=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('left=',''));
            var marLeft = parseInt($(this).attr('href').match(/marleft=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('marleft=',''));
            $(this).fancybox({'type':'iframe','transitionIn':'elastic','transitionOut':'elastic','width':fWidth,'height':fHeight,onStart: function () {
        //create a style that will position the fancy box relative to the element that clicked it.
            var leftT=posLeft;
            var topT=posTop;
            var style = document.createElement('style');
            style.type = 'text/css';
            style.innerHTML = '.shekhar{ top: ' + topT + 'px !important; left: ' + leftT + '% !important; margin-left: -' + marLeft + 'px !important;  }';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
            $('#fancybox-wrap').addClass("shekhar");
            }
            });
      }); 
    });
</script>
```

HTML is here:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="fancybox" href="http://iacampaigns.co.in/fiama/WAP/index.html?iframe&width=100&height=100&top=100&left=50&marleft=200">Iframe</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancybox" href="http://iacampaigns.co.in/fiama/WAP/index.html?iframe&width=200&height=200&top=100&left=50&marleft=100">Iframe</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

don'y know if version of fancybox you're using is 2.xxx, but in this case you can set the default margin like this:

```
$("#myfancy").fancybox({
margin     : [100, 0, 20, 0],
...
```

where margin set the position (px) of the wrapper (first number in the array is TOP)

Answer (score 1):

If using V2, the below helper method would do the trick on mobile devices:

```
$('.fancybox_success').fancybox({
    afterShow: function () {
        if ($portWidth <= $mobileBreakpoint) {
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        }
    },...
```

Answer (score 1):

A two pronged attack but by using position 'fixed' as opposed to absolute will disable scrolling an stop the frame from moving off the page

Internal CSS:

```
.fancybox-wrap { position:fixed !important; top: 100px !important; };
```

fancyBox jQuery:

```
onComplete  : function(){
        $('.fancybox-wrap').css({'position':'fixed', 'top':'100px'});
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For `fancyBox 2.0` and later as mentioned in this doc 
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

> **margin** :   Minimum space between viewport and fancyBox. Can be set as array - [top, right, bottom, left]. Right and bottom margins are ignored if content dimensions exceeds viewport
>   Integer, Array; Default value: 20

Example:

```
$('.fc-event').fancybox({
    autoCenter: true,
    margin: [100, 0, 0, 0], // [top, right, bottom, left]
    type: 'ajax',
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used fancybox myself but it looks like you need to set `centerOnScroll` to false and then position the `#fancybox-wrap` with css however you see fit.

Comment: Hi, the centerOnScroll is false by default and it will only make the fancybox fixed to the position which it opened. Which doesn't fullfill my requirement where the fancybox openup 150px top from the current view port and it still remains visible even after scroll.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //pass in the id of the link that was clicked and set the width and height for the iframe
    $.fn.fancybox_new = function (options) {
        for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            options._id = $(this[i]).attr("id");
            switch (options._id) {
                case "elementid": //set window size based on id
                    options.width = 375;
                    options.height = 190;
                    break;
            }
            $(this[i]).fancybox(options);
        }
    };

    $("a[rel*=formWin]").fancybox_new({
        onStart: function () {
            //create a style that will position the fancy box relative to the element that clicked it.
            if (this._id != "" && !$(this).hasClass(this._id)) {
                var style = document.createElement('style');
                var pos = $("#" + this._id).position();
                var mRight = parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("margin-right").replace("px")) + parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("padding-right").replace("px")) + parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("margin-left").replace("px")) + parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("padding-left").replace("px"));
                var mTop = parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("margin-top").replace("px", "")) + parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("padding-top").replace("px", "")) + parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("margin-bottom").replace("px", "")) + parseInt($("#" + this._id).css("padding-bottom").replace("px", ""));
                style.type = 'text/css';
                style.innerHTML = '.' + this._id + ' { top: ' + (pos.top + $("#" + this._id).height() + mTop) + 'px !important; right: ' + ($("body").width() - pos.left - $("#" + this._id).width() - mRight).toString() + 'px !important; left:auto !important; }';
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
                $('#fancybox-wrap').addClass(this._id);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible issues:

1. Fancybox is not getting absolute position or z-index. Solution: add `!important` in wrapper where position is absolute.
2. Div underneath them have absolute position too or positive z-index. Solution: give fixed position or relative to underneath divs and adjust or add negative z-index.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified fancybox library

> Version: 1.3.4 (11/11/2010)

for making this work:

In file jquery.fancybox.js  find line:

```
    $.fancybox.center = function() {
```

in this scope find:

```
     wrap
        .stop()
        .animate({
            'top' : parseInt(Math.max(view[3] - 20, view[3] + ((view[1] - content.height() - 40) * 0.5) - currentOpts.padding)),
```

and change it to:

```
    var topFromOptions = parseInt(Math.max(view[3] - 20, view[3] + ((view[1] - content.height() - 40) * 0.5) - currentOpts.padding));
    if (currentOpts.top) {
        topFromOptions = currentOpts.top;
    }
    wrap
        .stop()
        .animate({
            'top' : topFromOptions,
```

While revoking fancybox on selector pass option (for example):

```
top: '100px'
```

or what ever You want :)

```
$('#fancybox-selector').fancybox({ 
    top: '20px',
    // transitionOut:'elsatic'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this work fine for me

```
<script>
    $.fancybox({
       'width'     : 620,
       'height'    : 490,
       'speedIn'    :600,
       'speedOut'   :200,
                'onStart' :function()
                {

                        $("#fancybox-wrap").addClass('my_class');
                },
    });
</script>
    <style>
    .my_class{top:20px !important; }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, such a simple solution helped me:

**CSS**

```
#YOUR_FANCYBOX_WINDOW_SELECTOR {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

*FancyBox v3.5.2*