# fancybox top position

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using fancybox with centerOnScroll = true option, So when fancybox open it is being displayed in center of page and on scrolling mouse, fancybox moves with it. Problem is I wants to move fancybox near to top when its opening and i found a solution in this thread:

[How to position fancybox on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197877/how-to-position-fancybox-on-top)

I used this css trick too but problem is if i use this css code then fancybox is not moving on scroll.

```
#fancybox-wrap {
  top: -100px !important;
}
```

here my script link (click on gallery please) : http://travianstation.com/index.html

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it's position in relation to itself using margin or translateY:

```
#fancybox-wrap {
  margin-top: -100px;


#fancybox-wrap {
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}
```